# Why is it not possible to have a generic bean when i have also an Aspect targeting the bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Hi i have a rather specific question regarding Spring Aspects that leaves me puzzled. I played around with Springs and Apsects and and tried out a very simple Example to see how it works:

```java
@Component
public class Comment {
    private String text;
    private String author;

    public String get() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Around("execution(* aop.beans.*.*(..))")
    public void log(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Start Aspect for method: " + joinPoint.getSignature());
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

My configuration file:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("aop.beans")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ProjectConfig {
    @Bean
    public LoggingAspect aspect() {
        return new LoggingAspect();
    }
}
```

With that i used a simple Main method to play around with the concept a little:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProjectConfig.class);
        context.registerShutdownHook();

        CommentService service = context.getBean(CommentService.class);

        Comment comment = context.getBean(Comment.class);
        comment.setAuthor("Andreas");
        comment.setText("Hallo.");

        service.publishComment(comment);
        System.out.println(service.getClass());
    }
}
```

This worked fine but something strange happens when ich change the hirarchy of the comment class. I wanted to see what happens if the class implements a generic interface so i changed it as follows

```java
public class Comment implements Supplier<String>
```

I immediately get an error with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'aop.beans.Comment' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at aop.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

This left me wondering why that is? If i remove the generic superinterface or the aspect bean everthing works fine but both things together do not seem to fare well. Can someone provide an explanation? Is Spring not able to create a Proxy object if the class has a generic superclass?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that in markdown syntax, there is no need to write `@/MyAnnotation` in code blocks or in general. `@MyAnnotation` is just fine. I have just fixed that for you. I know on GitHub the `@` always means trouble, because it is interpreted as a user name. Here, that problem does not exist.

Comment: Instead of editing an answer into your question, please create an answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch I removed the "edit" section that just consisted of the (link-only) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the way Spring implements AOP.

When proxied class (`Comment` in your case) doesn't implement any interfaces, CGLib proxy is used. Basically, it generates a class which is subclass of proxied class. Thus, you can `getBean` by parent's class.

When there are implemented interfaces, Spring uses JDK dynamic proxies which don't extend the proxy class, but implement all its interfaces, thus you can't find a bean by it's class.

That's why it's always a good practice to autowire your beans by interface rather then by class.

### Solution

- You can force Spring to use CGLib proxies for AspectJ by annotating you configuration class `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`.
- If you want to use JDK Dynamic proxies, create interface for `Comment` and then use `context.getBean(YourInterfaceName.class)`.

Comment: While this answer is correct for Spring Core, let me add FYI that in Spring Boot the Spring Core default to use JDK proxies is overridden to automatically use CGLIB proxies. There, it is rather difficult to configure the original Spring default, because you need to some global config file setting for that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i found some further Spring documentation which explained the whole mechanism in further detail which i will link in a edit

Comment: Here's the Spring documentation referenced by @agoss94: [Proxying Mechanisms](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/proxying.html).